# Permanency Problem

Tags: professionalism, communication, career-development, company-policy

So here is my dilemma, I am currently employed in a finance company for about 5 months now, next month there will be a panel that will determine if the company decides to make me a permanent/regular employee. Currently I am reviewing before taking the **IELTS** examination because I am planning to go to **Australia** to apply for an **International Student Visa**. I decided to take the examination in October of this year but, all of that is not guaranteed. The panel now will ask me,

> "Why do we need to make you a permanent/regular employee despite the
>   fact that there is a chance that you will leave us in a few months?"

I am really enjoying my current job. I do not want to lose this job when I fail the exam.

What is the best answer to this question? or rather, is there a right answer to this question?

Comment: How do they know "that you will leave us in a few months"? On the other hand, if you're planning to leave them in a few months, why is the permanent position important to you? And what's the _dilemma_, anyway? What are the alternatives between which you're choosing?

Comment: @mustaccio my boss told the panel beforehand. The permanent position is important for me because if I do not get permanent I will be out of the job for a few months I need a stable income source and my plan is not a sure thing there is a chance that I will fail the examination. My plan is take the examination on October.

Comment: Is extending your contract not an option?

Comment: @Mars no, extending my contract is not an option. It is either I will be permanent or terminated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one is easy to answer: With a permanent job, you will of course not be leaving. Without a permanent job, you will feel free to look around.

(Having a permanent job will of course not stop you from doing what’s best for you, but you don’t have to tell them that).

Comment: +1 I have always been particularly passionate about the 5-year progression plan at all of the 6-month jobs I've moved between.

Answer (score 0):

You told your employer (via your boss) that you may be resigning in a few (eight) months. Your decision to resign depends on you passing (or not) the exam. In the meantime, you would like to enjoy the benefits of a full-time position.

Since you are studying for the IELTS, as you said, you're probably familiar with the saying: "You can't have your cake and eat it". You ate your cake when you told your boss that you were probably leaving, so your employer is (rightfully) acting on the assumption that you will.

If you are a good liar, you should try to convince the panel that you have changed your mind and are not going to jump the ship anymore. If they believe you, they might offer you a permanent position, all else being equal.

If you are not a good liar, take a chance by telling them that, though you might leave in a few months, you will work your butt off to produce as much value to the company as humanly possible, and then some. If they believe you, they might still keep you employed, while looking for your replacement.

---

It's always helpful to look at the situation from the other party's point of view. If you were the employer, what would convince you to offer a permanent position to an employee who just told you they are going to resign in October? Exactly.

---

In either case use this as a lesson to not tell anyone about your plans until they become a certainty.

Comment: I have not said that I will be resigning,I just said that there is a chance that I can go to Australia after I take the IELTS exam.

Comment: @lawrenceagulto That means the same thing....

Comment: What's the difference, if you read this sentence from the employer's point of view?

Comment: @mustaccio yeah, I made the mistake I told my boss that I have plans because I was so sure that I will be going to Australia in May but due to unforeseen events like the crisis on Australia my plan changed. I needed to take the IELTS now before they grant me an International Student visa

Comment: @mustaccio that is the same reason why I told my boss because my paper is being processed then the bush fires came the poof  my plans vanished

Answer (score -1):

In the comments you mention that you either become permanent or your contract will end.

That leaves you with three options:

- Choose between your job and school in Australia
- Lie. Tell them you've given up on Australia and then *stop talking about Australia around coworkers*.  If you get accepted, then you can choose Australia, but this will probably burn bridges with your current company and manager. If you *do* fail to get in, then no one knows anything.
- Try to convince them to take a chance with you. Since extending your contract is out of the question, this doesn't sound like it will work, but you could try. You can say things like "Australia isn't certain yet," "There is a very low chance of me getting in" etc. This isn't a total lie, but still won't go over very well if you do get accepted and quit after a few months.

Comment: Is there another way besides lying?

Comment: @lawrenceagulto I guess you could try to convince them to take a chance. If even an extension isn't possible, then it doesn't sound like they would want to take a risk. I guess I'll add that in though